# how debugging angularJS with firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I worked in javascript (jquery, ajax, ...) but I wanted to evolve so I put myself to the angularJS but I used to look in the network with firebug my variables send in POST or GET with my old Use but with angularJS I do not know how to verify the parameters that I send and that I receive,

How do i see these parameters

thank you in advance

Comment: did you check the request and response of the http request in the console?

Comment: While the library itself may change the API by which you make a call in your JavaScript code, the way that the browser makes the HTTP call should remain the same across frameworks (or absence of frameworks)-- `GET` parameters will be included as part of the URL as a query string, and `POST` parameters will be sent as an object in the request header (`body`, I think).  If you are not seeing your parameters as expected, it is possible you are not properly forming your requests via Angular.